# Ударение в выражении "земля обетованная"

Tags: этимология, фонетика

Почему ударение в прилагательном "обетованная" на "а", а не на "о"?

Корень слова — "обет". Земля обетованная — земля завещанная, данная в обет.

Если я обещаю сыну завещать квартиру. 
Квартира обетОвана сыну. Ударение на "о".

А если я хочу завещать другу землю.
Земля обетОвана другу.

Возьмём похожие по структуре слова:
ЗаколдОвана, расфасОвана, ... обетОвана....

Answer (score 4):

Попробую ответить.

Во-первых, обетованный, обетовать — церковнославянизмы. При этом широкого распространения они не получили, использование этих форм вне церковной лексики крайне сомнительно. Более того, форма "Земля обетованная" обычно воспринимается как нечленимая.
Русский же вариант — обещать, Щ здесь рефлекс исторического Т.

Во-вторых, форма проиходит не от "обет" напрямую, а от глагола "обетовать", т.е. это отглагольное прилагательное. Формы же "заколдована", "расфасована" происходят от приставочных глаголов и таким образом скорее всего являются причастиями.
Не следует искать фонетических аналогий между ними.

Все это наводит на мысль, что соответствующее причастие, существуй оно в русском языке, могло бы иметь форму *обетОванный*: "Земля, обетОванная Богом народу израилеву", при обычном "Земля обетовАнная". Но конструкции первого типа совершенно неупотребимы в живой речи.

Добавлю ещё, что вопрос разделения причастий и отглагольных прилагательных вне их грамматической функции в структуре предложения совершенно не разработан грамматистами, поэтому всё сказанное не может претендовать более чем на роль "понятийного" объяснения.